# Passing method as queue element

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, queue

Can I pass a method with return type void as a queue element?

```
void calcuate(){
 print...
}

//Queue<Obj> q = ... Queue initialization -- How?

q.put(caclulate());
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a `Queue<Runnable>`.

```
Queue<Runnable> q = new ArrayDeque<>();
q.add(() -> calculate());
```

and then you can get elements out of it and run it:

```
Runnable r = q.remove();
r.run();
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean by that.